# How rename a range of age in a for?

Tags: r

I want to create a dataframe with colnames will be a range for example 5-10 years, 10-15 years. And I created a "for" but this "for" named a columnames "group6", "group7", ... etc.

```
grupos <- 115/5
grupos <- (1:grupos)+5
name_grupos <- paste0("grupo_", grupos)
for(i in 1:length(name_grupos)){
grupo <- grupos[i]
name <- name_grupos[i]

datosedad[, name] = apply(datosedad[,c(grupo:(grupo+5))], MARGIN = 1, sum)

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data and expected outcome. I think `cut` might be what you're after. See `?cut` for details.

Comment: maybe you need to change `grupos <- (1:grupos)*5`